# How to get the rendered DIV's width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>`, which is dynamically controlled by the JS, for example, some children are added dynamically. Is it possible to know the width & height of the rendered DIV after the insertion/deletion are done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes,

after your operations to the div you can use

```
$('#divid').height()
```

and

```
$('#divid').width()
```